# Where is the cog icon to access a repo's settings in Bitbucket web interface?

Tags: bitbucket

I'm trying to add an issues tracker to a repo.

The documentation says to go to the repo's settings, by clicking on the cog icon. I can't see the cog icon anywhere in the interface.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Enable+an+issue+tracker

How do I get to my repo's settings?

Comment: Left side of the repository's homepage

Comment: Ah. Down the bottom. I think it used to be up the top. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cog icon is now near the bottom-left of the repository's homepage after Atlassian tweaked the BitBucket UI.